# How to roll back in subversion and simultaneously clear history?

Tags: sql, database, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

My SVN repository contains several folders for different projects. *'Desktop program'*, *'iOS app'*, *'Web app'* etc. All revision entries are shared between these (as it's under one repository. Revision #100 might be on the *'iOS app'* folder, revision #101 on the *'Web app'* folder etc).

What I want is to roll back to an earlier version on just *one* of these folders. Usually this is done with a 'reverse' SVN Merge as it's SVNs job to keep track of all history, even the bad times. I don't want that however. Lets say I have twenty commits on *'iOS app'* since revision #5. I want to rid these from history and I want that specific folder to return to revision #5. No one should ever again be able to check those twenty commits as they 'never happened'. Is this even possible?

I have two different machines I am interacting to SVN with. A Windows PC with VisualSVN and a Mac with Subversion on Terminal level. I would be thankful for a solution on either.

Comment: By VisualSVN do you mean VisualSVN Server or VisualSVN (Visual Studio extension)?

Comment: VisualSVN + Tortoise on client machine (where also Visual Studio has it) and/or the actual VisualSVN Server. I would be curious if it was possible only on the Server or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From client side, there is simply *no way* to do this. No matter if commandline, Tortoise, or any other client.

If you have access to the server account that owns the repository, then there is some chance - but it is quite complicated and may involve a nontrivial manual work.

Roughly, these are the steps:

- get the repository UUID - `svn info http://svnserver/svn/repo` - see the UUID line
- dump the svn repository: `svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > repo.dump`
- edit the dumpfile to exclude the commits

  a) either open it in `vi` and delete your undesired commits

  b) or use `svndumpfilter` command to filter them by path
- create new repository and import your modified repository into it:

  `svnadmin create /path/to/repo2`

  `svnadmin load < repo.dump`

  `svnadmin setuuid /path/to/repo2 THE_ORIGINAL_UUID`

Now, check that repo2 is working fine and has the content that you expect. If so, you can remove `repo` and rename `repo2` -> `repo`.

Keep in mind that manual changes to the dumpfile are extremely prone to errors, and often these errors can be quite difficult to discover. It is usually bad idea to do things like this.

Comment: Definitely not worth the hassle/risk in my case. I have always wondered if it was even possible, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just one note: `svnadmin dump` may have parameter -r, in which you can define revision range to dump (-r N:M)

Comment: Since the revision 'range' is intermixed between the various folders that dump command would affect other sub-projects something which I would rather not. Having multiple projects in one repository definitely lessens the SVN flexibility.

Comment: @Wollan - if you want "forget last N resisions", nature of commits before N haven't sense. And, lastly - you can use rev-range and --incremental for a bundle of dumps

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to roll back to an earlier version on just one of these folders. Usually this is done with a 'reverse' SVN Merge

Terrible... In order to return back **part of WC-tree** into *some previous revision* you have to `cd SUBTREE-ROOT & svn up -r REVNO` (commit from WC-root for this *modified WC* will create new revision in repo with partially rollbacked tree)

> No one should ever again be able to check those twenty commits as they 'never happened'

Cheated and rewritten history in SCM is **BAD IDEA**. And Subversion history is immutable, you have to change history using svnadmin tools and access-level, as @petr-kozelka wrote